# Friday Night Priestly Blessing When Children Away

Tags: birchas-kohanim, children

Are you allowed to bless your children on Friday night when they are not in your presence?
I recalled reading this somewhere but I have a mental blank as to what the answer is (I think somewhere in Meam Loez)

Thanks!

Comment: Why would it be forbidden? Do you mean should you?